# Restore SQL Server 2008 R2 transaction logs to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transaction-log

If I have SQL Server 2008R2 compatibility 90 production database and a SQL Server 2005 dev database.

Can I restore transaction logs from production to dev? Transaction logs restore from SQL Server 2008 R2 compatibility 90 to SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot restore from newer versions to olders versions of sql server.  The compatibility level of the database doesn't affect the on-disk structures.  For example, you can use page and row compression (sql 2008 features) in a database that is in 90 compat mode.